# Using Apache as a ruby server

Tags: ruby, apache, xampp

Is there any way I can use *Apache* as a ruby server ?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider the 'Passenger' module, see the [website](http://www.modrails.com/install.html). Yesterday I installed this module using their instructions on the website and it went well.

I did it via `gem install passenger`. I have not deployed anything as yet. Good luck with whatever option you choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eruby` and `libapache2-mod-ruby` packages then activate the ruby module with `sudo a2enmod ruby`.

Don't forget to create a configuration file `/etc/apache/conf.d/ruby.conf` and put something in here, like :

```
AddType text/html .rhtml
AddType text/html .rbx
DirectoryIndex index.rhtml index.rbx

<IfModule mod_ruby.c>
  RubyRequire apache/ruby-run
  RubyRequire apache/eruby-run

  <Files *.rbx>
    Options +ExecCGI
    setHandler ruby-object
    rubyHandler Apache::RubyRun.instance
  </Files>

  <Files *.rhtml>
    setHandler ruby-object
    rubyHandler Apache::ERubyRun.instance
  </Files>
</IfModule>
```